# nginx page not found error after certbot installation

Tags: nginx, ssl, flask, nginx-location, certbot

I have a http website (with Flask and nginx) which is up and running. I'm trying to install ssl with `certbot` and following their steps leads to a successful installation message (congratulations...) but refreshing my webpage leads to `404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)`.
This is the `nginx.conf` file after `sudo certbot --nginx`

```
server {
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/adviser/flaskblog/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

First, just remove this line:

```
return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

which causes 404 error to be returned.

If it doesn't help, change whole this block:

```
server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

to this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Also, you can try to change

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

to

```
return 301 https://www.yourdomain.com$request_uri;
```

(I had to replace `mydomain` with `yourdomain` due to some strange StackOverflow restrictions.)

Comment: thanks. It resolved the 404 issue but now https is striked through with a red line. I don't know why it is not recognizing my ssl (the path seems to be correct).

Comment: Did you only removed a line (my first suggestion) or totally modified server block?

Comment: I tried both and that gave me the clue for what is happening (I am answering it bellow). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i trying for 3 hours, and just remove return 404 for everything work

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what is the problem.

I was creating certificate for `www.mydomain.com`, but in reality I my domain was set to `mydomain.com` (no www). I was redirecting to `www` but either I was doing it wrong or certbot does not like redirects of that nature.

Long story short, I (re)issued certificate for `mydomain.com` and certificate worked like a charm!